# Dialogflow changing account linking speech response and display text

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

**tl;dr**
How can I customize the default speech of account linking in Dialogflow?

---

I would like to require sign-in with my Google Assistant ready application.

Following the guide steps in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking) I enabled the account linking for my `Default Welcome Intent` which asks the user to sign in.

The process works correctly getting the following speech response in Google Assistant showing the account linking card:

> It looks like your *{app name}* account is not linked yet.

I would like to customise the speech response giving additional information about the linking. Is there any way to modify that?

Thank you for your help.

---

**Update**

I tried to require [account linking at invocation time](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#account_linking_at_invocation_time) replacing the `textToSpeech` JSON value from `PLACEHOLDER_FOR_SIGN_IN` to my custom text, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the message that is displayed with the account linking box at this time. If you want to provide a response before the account linking card you could try calling `app.askForSignIn();` after providing the information to the user.

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#during_the_conversation

Comment: It's a big unfortunate despite I understand the workarounds. Thank you for your help.